# multiple script tags for three js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, three.js

I'm trying to work with three.js and really just html and js in general for the first time. I'm playing around with the example code and I found that even if I import the three.js file from the script tag in my Main.js file, it doesn't work unless I uncomment the script tag currently commented out. Why is this the case? Is there anyway i can run it in just my Main.js file without the first script tag?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- <meta charset="utf-8"> -->
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- <script src="node_modules\three\build\three.js"></script> -->
        <script src="js/Main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need threejs in order to use threejs. You can link it within your JS file, search 'ES6 import'

Answer (score 0):

please try this option: in your main html page `<script type="module" src="js/Main.js"></script>` and in your main.js  page import other js pages

Comment: this still results in an empty page, I also get an error that says that THREE.Scene is not a constructor when i do this

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

`<script src="node_module/three/build/three.js"></script>`

with

`<script type="module" src="node_module/three/build/three.module.js"></script>`

If you are importing module functions, it should be declared as a module.

(Not sure why type="module" should be part of the tag

`<script src="js/Main.js"></script>`

unless Main.js is *exporting* functions to be used outside of it.)